# React loop through an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, dictionary

```
  const [drInfo, setDrInfo] = useState([]);
  function showInfo(data, index) {
  if (data && data.data && data.data.length > 0) {
    const doctorData = data.data[index];
    setDrInfo({
      name: doctorData.Fname,
      lname: doctorData.Lname,
    });
  } else {
    return null
  }
  }
  
useEffect(() => {
   const url = "https://.../homepage/consts_list_homepage";

   fetch(url, {
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
     },
   })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((data) => showInfo(data, 0))
     .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);
  return ( <div>           
        {[drInfo].map((drInfo, index) => { return ( <div key={index}><Doctors info={drInfo} /></div> )})}    
           </div>
  );
}
```

I have a problem in react loop through an API. My API is going to provide the information of several doctors. I know there is no id and it's necessary for specifying different doctors, but now I wondered how to let it increase index and repeat the `<Doctors />` component for all data of the API. There is no error, but the component data is just rendered for `index=0`. I would be so thankful if you help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want list of doctors with unique id that you add on frontend.
you can just map over fetched data and add id as index or index + 1. then set your state as that new mapped data and use that state to render component.

```
const [drInfo, setDrInfo] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const url = "https://.../homepage/consts_list_homepage";

   fetch(url, {
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
     },
   })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((data) => {
        const doctorsData = data.data.map((item,index) => {
           return {
              id: +index + 1
              name: item.Fname,
              lname: item.Lname,
           }
        })
        setDrInfo(doctorsData)
      })
     .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  return ( <div>           
             {drInfo.map((info) => { return ( <div key={info.id}><Doctors 
              info={info} />
             </div> )})}    
           </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. It worked just by changing info to item.